# Gridview in Update Panel losing alternate row colouring on page change

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have a GridView in an update panel.

The GridView is styled so that each alternate row is a different colour.

When I change page on the GridView it loses the alternate row colouring. All other styles are maintained.

If I remove the update panel the GridView keeps the alternate row colouring after changing page.

Does anyone have any idea on what may be causing this or how to fix it?

Thanks,
Neil

EDIT:

Here is the aspx code

```
<div id="active-logbooks" class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="left-column">
        <asp:MultiView runat="server" ID="mlvLogbooks" >
            <asp:View runat="server" ID="vActiveLogbooks">
                <asp:GridView PagerSettings-Mode="NextPrevious" PagerSettings-Position="Top" PagerSettings-NextPageImageUrl="~/img/right-arrow.png" PagerSettings-PreviousPageImageUrl="~/img/left-arrow.png" AllowPaging="true" runat="server" ID="gvActiveLogbooks" PageSize="5" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="lesson stripe-me" OnRowDataBound="gvActiveLogbooks_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="gvActiveLogbooks_PageIndexChanging">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Logbook number" DataField="LogbookNumber" ItemStyle-CssClass="border" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Origin" DataField="Origin" ItemStyle-CssClass="border" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Order Reference" DataField="OrderReference" ItemStyle-CssClass="border" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Transfer Date">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lblTransferDate" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkTransferLogbook" CssClass="border" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainMaster$gvActiveLogbooks','Page$Prev')" id="lnkGridviewPrev" runat="server" class="left-arrow">Previous</a><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litBreaker" Text=" |" />
                <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainMaster$gvActiveLogbooks','Page$Next')" id="lnkGridviewNext" runat="server" class="right-arrow">Next</a>
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
    </div>
```

And this is the function that is called when the page change occurs:

```
protected void gvActiveLogbooks_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    HideShowGridViewPagerLinks(e.NewPageIndex);
    gvActiveLogbooks.DataSource = _logbooks;
    gvActiveLogbooks.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gvActiveLogbooks.DataBind();
}
```

Nowhere on the page is there anything done with colouring the GridView rows

```
    protected void gvActiveLogbooks_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        return;

    Literal transferLabel = (Literal)e.Row.Cells[(int)ActiveLogbookGridViewColumns.TransferDate].FindControl("lblTransferDate");
    transferLabel.Text = _logbooks[e.Row.RowIndex].TransferDate.ToShortDateString();

    HyperLink transferLink = (HyperLink)e.Row.Cells[(int)ActiveLogbookGridViewColumns.TransferLink].FindControl("lnkTransferLogbook");
    transferLink.Text = TransferLinkText;
    transferLink.NavigateUrl = "TransferLogbooks.aspx?id=" + Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

Comment: are you using ScriptManager ?

Comment: Does your GridView really **styled** with some css styles or you painting it with some code?

Comment: Yes have ScriptManager tags on the page. Fairly sure it's the css code that is styling it. I'll post the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that some interaction between your CSS classes and the postback is messing this up. What happens if you switch to  the `RowStyle` and `AlternateRowStyle` tags (example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowstyle.aspx)), and reference your CSS classes using the `CssClass` property on those tags?